# Implications as functions in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq, curry-howard

I read that [implications are functions](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Logic.html). But I have a hard time trying to understand the example given in the above mentioned page:

> The proof term for an implication P → Q is a function that takes
>   evidence for P as input and produces evidence for Q as its output.
>
> Lemma silly_implication : (1 + 1) = 2 → 0 × 3 = 0. Proof. intros H.
>   reflexivity. Qed.
>
> We can see that the proof term for the above lemma is indeed a
>   function:
>
> Print silly_implication. (* ===> silly_implication = fun _ : 1 + 1 = 2
>   => eq_refl
>        : 1 + 1 = 2 -> 0 * 3 = 0 *)

Indeed, it's a function. But its type does not look right to me. From my reading, the proof term for `P -> Q` should be a function with an evidence for `Q` as output. Then, the output of  `(1+1) = 2 -> 0*3 = 0` should be an evidence for `0*3 =  0`, alone, right?

But the Coq print out above shows that the function image is `eq_refl : 1 + 1 = 2 -> 0 * 3 = 0`, instead of `eq_refl: 0 * 3 = 0`. I don't understand why the hypothesis `1 + 1 = 2` should appear in the output. Can anyone help explain what is going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct until:

> But the Coq print out above shows that the function image is ...

I think you misunderstand the `Print` command. `Print` shows you the term associated with a definition, along with the type of the definition. It does *not* show the image/output of a function.

For example, the following prints the definition and type of the value `x`:

```
Definition x := 5.
Print x.
> x = 5 
>   : nat
```

Similarly, the following prints the definition and type of the function `f`:

```
Definition f := fun n => n + 2.
Print f.
> f = fun n : nat => n + 2
>   : nat -> nat
```

If you want to see the function's codomain, you have to apply the function to a value, like so:

```
Definition fx := f x.
Print fx.
> fx = f x
>    : nat
```

If you want to see the image/output of a function `Print` won't help you. What you need is `Compute`. `Compute` takes a term (e.g. a function application) and reduces it as far as possible:

```
Compute (f x).
> = 7
> : nat
```